# Eclipse Content Assist Showing Same Options Everywhere

Tags: eclipse, object, content-assist

I am using the latest version of Eclipse (4.3) and every time I go to use the dot operator it shows the same options every single time. Here is what it shows.

[image: Content Assist Problem]

As you can see it only displays things such as "create new object" which does not make any sense for an import. Can anyone explain why this is happening and show me how to get it back to normal?

Comment: How do the settings under `Window > Preferences, Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` look like?

Comment: Just checked. Turns out somehow SWT Template was the only thing suggested... I unchecked it and checked the other options. Post your reply as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check and activate the available autocompletion suggestion providers via `Window > Preferences, Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`.